# db:migrate order in Spree

Tags: ruby, migration, spree

I'm using [spree](http://spreecommerce.com/) and created a new payment gateway extension. The problem is, my newly created payment gateway gets created first before the core payment gateway of spree. Here's the error message.

> doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `gateway_options`

Comment: Please add more of your log messages, this is a bit thin

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Basically, there's a way to define the order in which extensions are **loaded** but not when their migrations are ran.

```
config.extensions = [:all, :site]
```

More info [here](http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/extensions.html#extension-load-orderand-initializers).

The way I do it, is simply by renaming the "db" folder of the extensions' migrations needing to be ran later. When the others have ran, I rename it back to its original name and run the migrations again. Dirty, but it works.

There could probably be a way to make a rake task and automate this.

Comment: Yeah. . . I did the same too, I guess we'll just have to wait for them to fix this. :(